# R merging with a preference

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose you have a matrix that consists of two columns of only 1's and 2's.

```
A B
1 2
2 2
1 1
2 1
2 1
2 2
2 1
```

How would you merge these two columns into one so that 2 always overwrites 1?

Desired Output:

```
C
2
2
1
2
2
2
2
```

Comment: Do you need to merge? Or create a new column?

Comment: I would like to create a new column C

Comment: That's not merging. What have you already tried? An ifelse-statement will cover it.

Comment: Ah thanks for the idea, I didn't think of that. I've come up with: `apply(matrix, 1,  function(z) ifelse(z[1] == 2 | z[2] == 2, 2, 1))`

Comment: `max(z[1],z[2])` would avoid the ifelse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the data is stored in a dataframe named `df`, you can use

```
df$C <- pmax(df$A, df$B)
```

to create a new column `C` with the desired result.

In the case of a matrix `m` you can use

```
m <- cbind(m, pmax(m[,1], m[,2]))
colnames(m) <- LETTERS[1:ncol(m)]
#> m
#     A B C
#[1,] 1 2 2
#[2,] 2 2 2
#[3,] 1 1 1
#[4,] 2 1 2
#[5,] 2 1 2
#[6,] 2 2 2
#[7,] 2 1 2
#> class(m)
#[1] "matrix"
```

Comment: Did you test this? It assigns 2 to all values, as `max(df$A,df$B)` yields 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but I mention in my question that I'm dealing with a matrix

Comment: You are right. I should have used `pmax` instead of `max`. Thanks for pointing this out, corrected in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Without ifelse:

```
df$C <- apply(df[,c("A","B")],1,max)
```

With ifelse:

```
df$C2 <- with(df, ifelse(A==1&B==1,1,2))
```

Result

```
> df
  A B C1 C2
1 1 2  2  2
2 2 2  2  2
3 1 1  1  1
4 2 1  2  2
5 2 1  2  2
6 2 2  2  2
7 2 1  2  2
```